# Large UITableViewCell stuttering

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, sdk

in my app I have a uiview with a tableview inside of it. This tableview consists of only one cell which is rather high (ca. 750) and contains alot of objects (uitextfields, uitextview, images, buttons, uiscrollview, smaller uitableview, etc).
I'm experiencing a small stuttering when scrolling the tableviewcell which I can't seem to get rid of.
Is it the large amounts of objects in one cell or should I distribute the objects into multiple cells to get rid of the stuttering?

Would be great if somebody has experienced the same issue and could help me out here a little.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: initialize all object before create UITabelViewCell

Comment: If your `UITableView` contains only one huge cell, it should be better to use a `UIScrollView`...

Comment: I do initialize all objects before displaying them in the cell.

Comment: I too had experienced the same string, and is clearly visible when we run on device, customization of tabelview cell and large amount of data is the main cause

Comment: you should scrollview instead of tableview.

Comment: The best thing to do in this case is to profile the app using Instruments (just click "profile" instead of "run"). Select the time profiler instrument and you will be able to see what is taking the time. Seeing as it is only one cell I'd suggest its probably the rendering time (i.e. transparent images, etc...).

Comment: @freshking please post it here when you a find a practical solutions for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this trick with tableHeaderView - works perfect for me! I'm also have a large hierarchy of subviews. ALso if you need some easy custom UI elements appearance/disappearance animations you can divide it into different cells. I love doing like that because of UITextViews and UITextFields - UITableViewController makes layout for keyboard appearance automatically.

Comment: What did you do with tableHeaderView?

Comment: Just put pretty large and complex view into tableHeader cause I don't want to handle and scroll my view manually when keyboard appears, UITableViewController did this work for me, I just changed my parent class from UIViewController to UITableViewController moved whole existing xib with large view into tableHeader and all fine.